# If I'm editing a file on a shared drive, how can I set it up so that the edits automatically show up in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-server

I'm trying to streamline the editing process and was wondering if it was possible to link a pathway in my office's shared drive to SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Page Viewer web part in your SharePoint site and link to your file share by UNC path. Then it will appears as if this content lives in SharePoint even though it is sitting on a file server.